# rpart same values in nodes

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I don't understand why there are 2 nodes with the same value 'A anim'. If I say 'yes' in the first node, I can't say 'no' in 5th. All data are categorical variables.

[image]

Comment: That is fine I guess, rpart does a binary split and a decision tree reduces observation on each split , it doesn't mean it can't use the variable in further split which was used earlier.

Comment: The split is not 100% accurate, so you have some "leakage" which is picked up down the line.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Is there something I can use to make 100% accurate decision tree?

Comment: Nothing is  certain but two things. Taxes and death.